# SlugRelatedField makes no difference for Django Rest Framework serialization

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

All,

I am trying to replace a standard foreignkey field serialization w/ a field from the related model.

Here is some code:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  bar = models.ForeignKey("Bar")

class Bar(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Foo
    fields = ("id", "name", "bar", )
  bar = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field="name")
```

But nomatter what I do, it serializes using the pk of the bar instance, instead of its name.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ("id", "name", "bar", )
```

That should return just the name in a string format.

Comment: D'oh!  That suggestion did work.  However, I saw that my original problem was just an indentation one; redefining the "bar" field had been done in the "Meta" section of the class definition instead of on the class itself.